# Not able to edit a Marketing Cloud Asset using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, edit, asset

So the error I am getting is related the fact that SFMC was not able to locate my asset

So I used this : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/updateAsset.html

This is my payload, I provided the content property :

```
{
    "content": "the content is correct in format because I have send it in POST request to create before editing"
}
```

I tried by adding ***category*** object in the payload, and ***entrepriseId*** hoping that SFMC will be able to locate the asset ID, but still nothing.. ( Tried them separated, together .. same reuslt )

I tried with name property alone as well but nothing..

so my endpoint is this : https://mcyrkmypz9w3xcb5pdye9dqwpuxy.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/352325

And my response is always this :

> {
>
> "message": "Update failed. Unable to locate asset. Invalid asset id provided.",
> "errorcode": 30001,
> "documentation": ""
>
> }

Any help would be much appreciated in this, Thank you guys !

Comment: are you making the call in the correct MID? account context is done by the token call

Comment: How can I know ? @EazyE

Comment: All I know is that the token I am getting, is a token I et from sending the same account_id as the business unit ID where the asset is located

Comment: Look at your token response it tells you what account it is and does assetid 352325 exist in that account

Comment: the token response ? it has only expiration date, type of token, urls, etc.. it does not tell the account_id, the account id is something I am sending in the payload to get the token.. so, is that what you're asking me to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried by myself and got the same issue like you mentioned.

After I had several attempts I found that in order to update the asset you would need to put these attributes: **id, assetType, category, name, customerKey**. Value of these attribute can get from [Get asset by ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getObjectById.html) API call

So the payload is going to be:

```
{
    "id": "Your asset ID",
    "assetType": {
        "id": "Asset type ID",
        "name": "Asset type name",
        "displayName": "Asset type display name"
    },
    "category": {
        "id": "Folder ID",
        "name": "Folder name",
        "parentId": "Parent folder ID"
    },
    "name": "Asset Name",
    "customerKey": " Asset Customer Key",
    "content": "Your new content"
}
```

Comment: KING!! Worked like a charm!!